# Using "segmentation_models_pytorch" with Unet++

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I was trying to use [segmentation_models_pytorch](https://smp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#id2)" with Unet++. I tried to look at the example at [HuBMAP - Pytorch smp Unet++](https://www.kaggle.com/code/nayuts/hubmap-pytorch-smp-unet). My understanding Unet++ returns 4 outputs (as part of deep supervision). But in the example, I notice it is only returning one output. I think I'm missing something here.